# Template universal reference in c++ does not compile

Tags: c++, c++14, forwarding-reference

I'm having trouble understanding why my code doesn't compile here. I'm getting a lot of error messages from the standard library, along the lines of

```
main3.cpp:10:20:   required from ‘void addAndCout(T&&) [with T = const char (&)[11]]’
main3.cpp:20:28:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/alloc_traits.h:450:27: error: forming pointer to reference type ‘const char (&)[11]’
       using pointer = _Tp*;
                           ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/alloc_traits.h:453:39: error: forming pointer to reference type ‘const char (&)[11]’
       using const_pointer = const _Tp*;
```

This doesn't make sense to me since I thought T&&, when T has not been deduced, is a universal reference, which should be able to bind to an rvalue or lvalue. This example posted is me trying to copy a section from Scott Meyer's "Effective Modern C++" where I was reading about universal references. [Photo of example from the book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDMLf.png)

I'm just wondering why this won't compile or what I'm missing here, since as far as I can tell it's effectively the same to the example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

template<typename T>
void addAndCout(T &&name)
{
    std::vector<T> v;

    cout << name << endl;
    v.emplace_back(std::forward<T>(name));
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::string name {"test"};

    addAndCout(std::string("rvalue")); // FINE      move rvalue instead of copying it
    addAndCout("New string");          // ERROR     make a new string instead of copying
    addAndCout(name);                  // ERROR     copy lvalue
}
```

Comment: Could you explain the purpose of the local vector? It gets destroyed when the function returns so storing the value in it is redundant anyway.

Answer (score 3):

There cannot be a `vector` of references, nor a vector of C-style arrays. The line `std::vector<T> v;` fails to compile when the argument is an lvalue and/or a C-style array.

Your code differs from the book in that you do `std::vector<T> v;` whereas the book does not.

To support the usage `addAndCout(name);` you could change the vector definition to:

```
std::vector< typename std::remove_cv<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>::type > v;
```

(the `remove_cv` is because there cannot be a vector of const objects either).

To support the C-style array it would be simplest to add an extra overload:

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
void addAndCout(T (&name)[N])
{
     // do whatever...
}
```

Comment: The template argument to `vector` also cannot be `const`, an array, or a function. So probably `std::decay` would be better than `std::remove_reference`.

Comment: @aschepler I added `remove_cv`. I think the behaviour of `decay` on arrays is probably not appropriate for this use case, the intent would be to store a copy/move of the argument. Although I am not really clear on what the intent is, since it is redundant to store the item in a local vector

Answer (score 1):

- When you do `addAndCout(std::string("rvalue"));` this is rvalue
  reference and template parameter T is std::string and
  `this::std::vector<std::string> v;` which is valid.
- But when you do `addAndCout("New string");` T is deduced as reference to array of const char, and you can't have vector of references
- And when you do `addAndCout(name);` you are passing l-value ref, and
  T becomes `std::string&` and similar you can't have vectors of references.